# Russian characters in with SetWindowTextW in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, encoding, character-encoding

I basically use this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool SetWindowTextW(IntPtr hWnd, string lpString);

SetWindowTextW(HWnd, "лфорфпылвоарпфлыьтвмлафывафыва")
```

to set the title of a window but the title ends up as:

```
ð╗Ðäð¥ÐÇÐäð┐Ðïð╗ð▓ð¥ð░ÐÇð┐Ðäð╗ÐïÐîÐéð▓ð╝ð╗ð░ÐäÐïð▓ð░ÐäÐïð▓ð░
```

I think that this has something to do with incorrect encoding.
Interestingly it seems to work if I type the string into a TextBox and send the property `textbox.Text` to the same function.

I get a similar string from an API so just typing it in and saving the output is not possible.

(I know the text in the code above is just random characters but the result is a similar mess with actual words)

Comment: Unicode is two bytes.  Other encoding methods are one byte.  To save space the other encoding methods take the one byte character 0x80 to 0xFF and map two a two byte unicode character.  So I think you need to change : CharSet = CharSet.Unicode

Comment: @jdweng with CharSet.Ansi and CharSet.None are 㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿 Charset.Auto seems to work, even if VisualStudio warns you about it. Thank you!

Comment: I take that back, apparently it doesn't work reliably

Comment: OK, so running it with CharSet.Auto works as a standalone app (fx 4.8, C# 8) but not in my IDEs Run-Window...

Comment: The lpString has the wrong encoding.  If it had the correct encoding than the API would be working.  The text box what Font is being used?  You are displaying correctly in the textbox because the Font is compatible with the encoding.  A textbox is only 8 bit and doesn't work with unicode characters (two bytes). I'm not sure why you are using SetWindowTexW (wide) instead of just the setWindowText.  See following : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-how-to-change-the-output-encoding-scheme-of-the-console/

Comment: Not if the API was applying the wrong encoding.  Try :  Console.WriteLine("abc", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) to send a [`WM_SETTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settext) message to a *foreign* Window:

From the Remarks section of [SetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtextw):

> If the target window is owned by the current process, SetWindowText
>   causes a WM_SETTEXT message to be sent to the specified window or
>   control. If the control is a list box control created with the
>   WS_CAPTION style, however, SetWindowText sets the text for the
>   control, not for the list box entries.
>
> To set the text of a control in another process, send the WM_SETTEXT
>   message directly instead of calling SetWindowText.

**`Charset = CharSet.Auto`** is used to correctly marshal the string. The target operating system requirements are determined automatically (C# would mark it as `ANSI` otherwise).
See also: [Charsets and marshaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/charset?view=netframework-4.8).

---

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

const uint WM_SETTEXT = 0X000C;

IntPtr hWnd = [TheWindowHandle];
IntPtr russianPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("лфорфпылвоарпфлыьтвмлафывафыва");
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, russianPtr);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(russianPtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with the L for literal prefixing.

```
SetWindowTextW(HWnd, L"лфорфпылвоарпфлыьтвмлафывафыва")
```